# Setting inputs as values from a string of GET request parameters with JS?

Tags: javascript, get

We want to set various inputs to the values contained in a str `inputValueStr` obtained like so:

```js
  const form = document.querySelector('#theForm');
  var object = Object.values(form).reduce((obj, field) => { obj[field.name] = field.value; return obj }, {});
  delete object[""];
  const inputValuesStr =  new URLSearchParams(object).toString()
```

The string looks like "foo=&bar=123&baz=examplestr&whatever=". What's a good way to set the `#theForm`'s inputs to the values from the string (ie. make inputs of bar = 123, baz = "examplestr", and other inputs null)?

We're unsure if we're missing something as we don't know what to search for so apologies if this is a stupid question. If so please feel free to redirect us to another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to get all the variables in the URL:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```

Then, you can iterate over every parameter and set the form's input to its value:

```js
urlParams.forEach((val, key) => {
   const inputEl = document.querySelector('#theForm [name="'+key+'"]');
   if(inputEl) 
       inputEl.value = val;
});
```